# Azure Functions 2 local deployment MissingMethodException [Updated]

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

**UPDATED**

There are two Windows Systems, one dev machine running Visual Studio and all SDKs bundled within, and one test system with .Net Core Runtime, .Net Core SDK and Azure Functions Core Tools.

Creating a Azure Functions v2 application on the dev machine runs on the test machine without problems.

Now, we add a startup routine for the Functions App, requiring the NuGet Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.0.0 (which requires updating the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package as well to 2.2.0)

The startup routine looks like

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(AFunctionsTest.Startup))]
namespace AFunctionsTest
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                 .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                 .Build();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
        }
    }
}
```

The adapted Functions App runs fine on the dev machine. On the test machine, the function start fails with error:

> fail: Host.General[0]
>         A host error has occurred
>       System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IWebJobsBuilder.get_Services()'

As linked by Joey [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1718), this might by a problem of different versions getting targeted/loaded. As I only did the steps mentioned above, I cannot tell, which versions are mismatching and how to extract this information. How can I fix this dependency issue?

(Thanks to Joey for the input)

---

**OLD Post**

I have created a set of Azure Functions with Visual Studio. I can compile and start  the functions from Visual studio without problems. Now, I want the functions (all web-triggered, no timer or else) to run on a seperate machine for testing. After installing .Net Core Runtime and SDK as well as the Azure Functions Core tools, the  system tries to start up. But the startup stops with an error telling

```
fail: Host.General[0]
  A host error has occurred
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IWebJobsBuilder.get_Services()'.
```

The functions use DI as provided and I already treid adding the Extensions explicitely via NuGet, but still it is not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: there's really not enough info here for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide more details like the references you installed and so on. Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1718) you could refer to.

Comment: @joey-cai thanks for the link. I updated accordingly, as I am not capable fixing the issue so far

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you get anywhere with this?